# Semantics of putting main content in a list item

Tags: html, html-lists, semantic-markup

As the title says, I'm considering putting the main content of my HTML pages inside a list item. I don't know how semantic that is. Articles on lists don't get heavily specific (as perhaps they shouldn't) on what is considered an item of a list. So consider the following:

```
<ul>
    <li><h5>Main Content</h5>
        <ul>
            <li><article><h1>Article Title</h1>
                    <p>Here's my main, feed-ready content.</p></article></li>
            <li><aside>Related Links</aside></li>
        <ul>
    </li>
    <li><aside>Recommended Links</aside></li>
</ul>
```

Now, I come about this arrangement for styling purposes (I know... worst place to start a semantics conversation). My `<ul>'s` are styled with `display:table;` and `<li>'s` styled `display:table-cell;` elsewhere in my markup. So it'd be sooo convenient if I could just carry that down to my main content as well.

Not so much looking for best practice (although feel free to comment) but if this is *semantically* an incorrect thing to do.

Comment: I don't know if this is a (stripped) real example, so just to be sure: the first `aside` should probably be a child of the `article` (if the "Related Links" are related to the article content). And the `h5` may not be appropriate here, at least the content of it.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up on the asides. I've read probably a dozen articles that contradict each other on when and where to use asides. (I guess you really have to go with your gut sometimes.) But yeah, this is not code from a real project, just a for-instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as they are child elements of the `li` and **not** sibling elements, **it is semantically fine and valid** in HTML4 and HTML5.

**An example of what is fine:**

```
<ul>
    <li><article>Article Here</article></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

**An example of what isn't fine:**

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <article>Article here.</article>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

The permitted contents section [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html) explains more about what a `li` can contain (basically any [flow element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/common-models.html#common.elem.flow), shown below).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should do that.

The main content of your page could certainly be put into a `ul`. But it depends on the kind of content if it is appropriate.

A simple example where it would make sense: a page titled "My favorite fruits", containing a `ul` where every fruit is a `li`.

But in your case, the content of the list is not related in any meaningful sense. What is your list *about*? A list of … well, what, page components? If you go this route, you could also use a `ul` for a list of paragraphs, or a list of words in a sentence, or a list of letters in a word.

I don't say that you "MUST NOT" do it (the spec is pretty open about the use of [`ul`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element)), but I advise against it, in the same sense that I'd advise against the use of:

```
<ul>
  <li><h1>Fruits!</h1></li>
  <li>Welcome to my site.</li>
  <li>I write about fruits here and I hope you enjoy your visit.</li>
  <li><h2>What I like about fruits</h2></li>
  <li>They are tasty.</li>
  <li>And healthy.</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>Hi, </li>
  <li>my </li>
  <li>name </li>
  <li>is </li>
  <li>John. </li>
</ul>
```

Using a list in such a not-so-meaningful way might also confuse some screenreader users, as they often have functions to jump to lists on the page and navigate by list items etc. Also some screenreaders might announce "List item" before reading your content.

You need it only for styling. So please use `div` elements (with classes), instead.

Comment: Yeah, after I plopped all my content areas into <ul>s the markup just didn't feel right. It was just a nice fix for a slightly cleaner stylesheet (like maybe three lines, psh). It's a good conversation to have though. I've seen sites lately (even W3.org) go a bit crazy on the use of lists from breadcrumbs to image galleries to entire header layouts.